# Binding to Map entry

Tags: drools

I have a rule `maxNumConsecutiveCubicCustomersPerLocation` as such:

```
Customer(..., $location: location, $consecAndWaitingMap: consecAndWaitingMap)
```

and all I want to do is to retrieve the `entry` of `$consecAndWaitingMap` with key `$location` (which is an enum type).

In the `then` part of the rule I can easily print the entry as so `System.out.println($location+": "+$consecAndWaitingMap.get($location));`, but I may not bind to it:

```
$consec: $consecAndWaitingMap.get($location)
```

The compile time error given:

```
Unable to resolve ObjectType '$consecAndWaitingMap.get'
```

I have imported all the necessary classes (`import java.util.Map; import ...Customer;`) so that can't be the problem. Other workarounds, such as fixing `$location`, or accessing by `[]`, or by first binding to `Customer`and  then retrieving my map using `consecAndWaitingMap: HashMap() from $customer.getConsecAndWaitingMap()` give similar errors.

How can I bind to  `$consecAndWaitingMap.get($location)`? If that's not possible, any ideas for a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind your entry in the same line as the other variables. The following code should work :

```
Customer(..., $location: location, $consecAndWaitingMap: consecAndWaitingMap, $mapEntry : consecAndWaitingMap.get(location))
```

Note that you can't use the other variables when binding the new one, you need to use the actual "location" field. (replacing "location" with "$location" will give an error)